# how to use matlab to smooth the edge of a picture

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]I get a picture below but the picture has a very ugly edges. 
I want to use matlab programming to smooth the edges of the picture and make it look more pretty,any ideas or ways make sense?

thank you!!!

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: i just got this picture(every dot's rbg), and i just want add some points to make the edges more smooth,but i dont have a good idea about the algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option (edited):

```
I = im2double(imread('ht4Za.jpg'));
% Segment the object:
gs = rgb2gray(I);
Object=~im2bw(gs, graythresh(gs));

% Smoothen the mask:
BW = bwmorph(bwconvhull(Object), 'erode', 5);
Mask=repmat(BW,[1,1,3]);

% Iterate opening operation:
Interp=I;
for k=1:5
    Interp=imopen(Interp, strel('disk',20));
end

% Keep original pixels, add the newly generated ones and smooth the output:
Interpolated(:,:,1)=medfilt2(imadd(I(:,:,1).*Object, Interp(:,:,1).*~(BW==Object)), [4 4]);
Interpolated(:,:,2)=medfilt2(imadd(I(:,:,2).*Object, Interp(:,:,2).*~(BW==Object)), [4 4]);
Interpolated(:,:,3)=medfilt2(imadd(I(:,:,3).*Object, Interp(:,:,3).*~(BW==Object)), [4 4]);

% Display the results:
Masked=imadd(Interpolated.*im2double(Mask), im2double(~Mask));
imshow(Masked);
```

Result:

[image]

It's a bit rough, but that'll give you a start. You can try to fiddle with the number of iteration and the size of the circular filter and the median filter. Try changing the median with average, etc.

Comment: Adding your result image will greatly improve number of people up-voting your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [**imopen**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) to morphologically open the RGB image (dilation and erosion). The second input argument to imopen function is a structuring element which defines the amount of smoothing required in the morphological operation. For example, below is a code where I apply a disk structuring element of radius 10.

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht4Za.jpg');
imopenBW = imopen(img, strel('disk',10));
imshow(imopenBW)
```

Comment: This approach is easy to implement but it blurs the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isocontour` [1] edge detection and then average adjacent pixels along the contour to smoothen the boundary.

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30525-isocontour

Comment: Averaging a coloured image may to be as easy as for grey-scale images, but why shouldn't it work, given an appropriate averaging function?

Comment: Absolutely. It is definitely much easier to find edges in gray-scale images, but it would not complete the task of smoothing the image.

Comment: That is why I suggest a two step algorithm: (1) detect contour (2) smoothen it